# Replace pattern in vim from first non space character

Tags: regex, vim

```
   Line1 starting after some initial space
    Line2 starting after few initial space
      Line3 starting after someother initial space
```

In Vim, i want to change some pattern not on all line, but per each line starting from non white-space character horizontally. Suppose on each line, right from L (first non space character in that line) i want to insert multiple space between each words.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command for adding another space:

```
:%s/\v\w+\s/& /g
```

Explanation:

```
:s   command
%    entire file
/    delimiter
\v   regex magic mode
\w+  at least one word character
\s   a whitespace character
&    replace match with itself plus a space
g    match multiple times per line
```

Comment: How about adding a bit of explanation?